# Is there a way to extract the year data from a date in ORACLE? Counting user votes

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hi I am creating a database that tracks how many times a user votes for one of our products.

Is there a way that I can change the query below to count the max number of votes each year? I'm using Oracle SQL developer

The creates tables are structured as

```
Members(username, email, pwd) 
Votes (username*, prodCode*, score, voteDate)
```

note:

```
SELECT username, count(username)
FROM Votes NATURAL JOIN members
GROUP BY username, email
HAVING COUNT(*) >= All(SELECT count(username)
                   FROM Votes v1
                   GROUP BY username);
```

Comment: You haven't said which RDBMS you are using.  I can rule out Sql Server since your query isn't valid for that RDBMS, but which I'm not sure.  Almost all RDBMS's have a function to return portions of a date however.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but something like this maybe?

```
SELECT username, 
       extract(year from voteDate) as vote_year, 
       count(*) as votes_per_year,
       max(count(*)) over (partition by extract(year from voteDate)) as max_votes_per_year
FROM Votes vt
GROUP BY username, extract(year from voteDate);
```

This will give you the count for each user and year and the max count for each year in every row. (Note the members table is not necessary for this as you apparently don't need any column from that).

If you need to show a zero count for years where nobody voted (or one specific user didn't vote), then you'll need something like this:

```
with years as (
   select 2009 + level as year
   from dual
   connect by level <= 21
)  
SELECT username, 
       y.year, 
       count(vt.username) as votes_per_year,
       max(count(vt.username)) over (partition by y.year) as max_votes_per_year
FROM years y 
  LEFT JOIN Votes vt on y.year = extract(year from vt.voteDate)
GROUP BY username, y.year
order by y.year, username;
```

This will generate a list of years between 2010 and 2030 "on-the-fly" using a common table expression (`with ...`). You can adjust the CTE to extend or narrow the number of years.

Answer (score 0):

For this you'd better have a table with years (or at least a table of number that could help you set up a set of years).

```
SELECT
    username
    , MAX(cnt) AS mcnt
FROM (
    SELECT
        username
        , count(username) AS cnt
    FROM members 
    CROSS JOIN Years
    INNER JOIN Votes ON (
        members.username = Votes.username -- using an INT here would be more efficient
        AND
        Votes.voteDate >= Years.firstJanuary
        AND
        Votes.voteDate < Years.firstJanuary+ 1 Year -- Pseudo code, you didn't mention any DBMS
    )
    GROUP BY username, prodCode, Years.firstJanuary
) AS X
```